# Cloth simulation bouncing and blowing around

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm looking for some help to find out why this cloth simulation is bouncing around. I'm hanging the pants by hooks and no matter what settings I try, the pants bounce and fly around. I'm looking for the pants to just drop and settle.

Edit: I'm wondering if there may be something odd with the mesh that is causing self-collisions to over-react.

[Blend file](http://hunchbox.com/pants2.zip)

Thank you for any suggestions.
[image]

Comment: Show the settings for the cloth modifier. Stiffness and Damping should help you control the movement. Read through the manual to understand what the settings do: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/cloth/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I tried all the cloth presets and they seem to cause the same issues regardless. I've had good success with the cloth settings in general, but I'm wondering if there is something odd with the mesh that is causing crazy self collisions.

Comment: I have read the manual, but certainly don't understand the ramifications of every setting.

Comment: Try moving one by one, so that you understand what each of them do. If you move all of them simultaneously you will have no control.

Comment: Have you enabled Pressure , it makes things go really messy , reduce its value if you have enabled it

Comment: Pressure is not enabled.